# refreshing div with dynamically created data via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to reload a `div` that has been dynamically created data via AJAX, but I'm getting a 403 forbidden error. Maybe something is wrong in what I am doing. Would you mind to helping me please. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="curr-elem">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3>Elementary Subject</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="curr-elem-content">
        <table id="curr-elem-tble">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var html;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add_subject.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'func_numbr':'2' },
    success: function(data) {
        var activator;
        var disabler;
        var counter_sub = 0 ;

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if (data[i].subj_status == "0") {
                classToAddInactve = "inactiveButton";
                DisableInactve = "disabled=\"disabled\""
                classToAddActve = "";
                DisableActve = ""
            }
            else {
                classToAddInactve = ""
                DisableInactve = ""
                classToAddActve = "inactiveButton";
                DisableActve = "disabled=\"disabled\""
            }

            html = "<tr>";

            html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject[" + counter_sub + "]' rel='" + data[i].subj_id + "' value='" + data[i].subj_name + "' readonly='readonly'></td>";
            html += "<td><input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='activate[" + counter_sub + "]' name='active' class='button active modal2 " + classToAddActve + "' value='Apply' " + DisableActve + "> ";
            html += "<input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='inactivate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button inactive modal2 " + classToAddInactve + "' value='Remove from list' " + DisableInactve + "></td>";
            html += "</tr>";

            $('#curr-elem-tble').append(html);

            counter_sub = counter_sub +1;
        });
    }     
});
```

JS that will trigger the `div` refresh:

```
$('.active').live('click', function() {
    var prev = $(this).parent().prev().find('input[type=text]');
    var valText = $(prev).val();
    var relVal = $(this).parent().prev().find('input[type=text]').attr('rel');
    var div = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

    $("[id*="+div+"]").hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add_subject.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'func_numbr': '7',
            'subjct_name': valText,
            'subjct_id': relVal
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mask2').hide();
            $('#loading-window').hide();
            $("[id*=" + div + "]").load("[id*=" + div + "]");
        }     
    });
});
```

Comment: first of all check the URL add_subject.php. HTTP 403 means that the server can be reached, but it declined to allow the requested access.

Comment: try replacing the existing div instead of appending..

Comment: @Adam here my whole project im working on http://pastebin.com/hzLcrRsL

Comment: i think the problem is .load() call, it expects a proper url, something like "add_subject.php", what you are passing doesn't look like a url

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` callback you're using the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method wrong. `load()` expects a URL, not a selector.

You probably meant to do something like this instead:

```js
    success: function(data) {
        $('#mask2').hide();
        $('#loading-window').hide();
        $("[id*=" + div + "]").html(data.someHTMLvar);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if `add_subject.php` can really be accessed by accessing it from your browser. If that works then there's no problem with the server.

Like lifo has said you're using `$.load` the wrong way. `$.load` accepts a url as the first parameter.

```
  success: function(data) {
        $('#mask2').hide();
        $('#loading-window').hide();
    }
```

Aside from that you might be better of using a templating library like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). This doesn't really look good:

```
    html = "<tr>";

    html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject[" + counter_sub + "]' rel='" + data[i].subj_id + "' value='" + data[i].subj_name + "' readonly='readonly'></td>";
    html += "<td><input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='activate[" + counter_sub + "]' name='active' class='button active modal2 " + classToAddActve + "' value='Apply' " + DisableActve + "> ";
    html += "<input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='inactivate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button inactive modal2 " + classToAddInactve + "' value='Remove from list' " + DisableInactve + "></td>";
    html += "</tr>";
```

Or if you don't want to use a templating library then build the html from the server so you can just use `$.load` to load the html that you need.